# C# Mvc Api Xml cannot convert string to XML in Powershell

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, api, powershell

**.NET APP**

I have an MVC 4.5 application with an Api controller that returns an xml document. It looks something like this:

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class GetDataController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyStruct> Get()
        {
            //code to build IEnumerable<MyStruct> ReturnList goes here...
            return ReturnList;
        }
    }
}
```

**POWERSHELL**

When I run the app, I can see the XML properly displayed in the browser.

[image]

I can retrieve the web content as a string with powershell with:

```
$doc = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://localhost:PORT#/api/...")
```

The returned string looks like:

```
[{"Prop1":"Value1","Prop2":"Value2"},{"Prop1":"Value1", "Prop2":"Value2"}]
```

[image]

**THE ERROR**

However, I am get an error when trying to convert that string to xml via

```
$xmlDoc = [xml]$doc
```

The error reads:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

[image]

**I'VE TRIED USING:**

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($xmlURL,'c:\temp\file.xml')
$xmlSchedule = [xml](Get-Content 'c:\temp\file.xml')
```

as well as

```
$bomutf8=[system.text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetPreamble()
if(($a=(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Downloadstring($xmlURL)).startsWith($bomutf8))
{
    [xml]$a=$a.remove(0,$bomutf8.length)
}
```

**THE QUESTION**

How can I circumvent this error? Ideally, I would like to fix this error on the server-side so that end-users do not experience the same problem.

Comment: That string is not valid XML. Looks more like JSON.

Comment: Add GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseDataContractSerializer = true;
 to Application_Start of Global to force MVC to return Xml instead of JSON.

Comment: You're right. It does. I can't believe that skipped my mind... But why would it appear as XML when I view it in browser?

Comment: Sounds like IE is doing nice things for you.  You can get this to xml using `[xml]($doc | ConvertFrom-Json)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Haha, as dumb as I feel right now, I can at least say that I use Chrome when I debug.
I'm just going to stick with the "I'm a noob" excuse.

Comment: Correction: `$doc | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Xml`